# TWS alert questions

Tags: tivoli, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

Please let me know the answers to these questions on Tivoli Workload Scheduler.

How could TWS warn the admins when the job didn’t kick off as scheduled?
How could TWS warn the admins if the job is running longer than expected?
How could TWS send email about the completion of the job  once it is finished without errors?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from TWS 8.4 you can define an event rule with two correlated events. In your case, these two events need to be defined of type Job Status Changed and with the property Status set to "Running". It needs also to define in this rule a timeout of X seconds/minutes/hours and associate the timeout to a SendEmail action. Then when the timeout expires and the status remains the unchanged (running) the email is sent automatically. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what version of TWS you are running. But if you are talking about versions > 8.3 all these alerts and notifications can be set up in the Tivoli Dynamic Workload Console (TDWC).

These new versions of TWS introduce the new concept of 'even-driven' scheduling, where you can set events and triggers for each job, in which you could include an email being sent or forward the event to an event management system.